# TypeError: Cannot set property 'antennas_select_input' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multiple ui-select in angularjs but when I try to start data in a model it throws me an error:

[image: error]

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="control_access.antennas_select_input" theme="bootstrap" search-enabled="true"
                     reset-search-input="true" close-on-select="false">
            <ui-select-match class="ui-select-match">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices class="ui-select-choices" repeat="antennasInput in (antennasDataInput) track by $index">
              {{antennasInput.name}}
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>




$scope.editForm = function () {
            $scope.control_access.antennas_select_input = [<%= AntennaInstalled.all.to_json %>];
        }

        var action = $("#action_control_access").val();
        if(action == "edit"){
            $scope.editForm();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating `$scope.control_access`? It's either null or undefined, that's your issue.

Comment: I do not have it instantiated, at what value should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.control_access = {};
$scope.editForm = function () {
    $scope.control_access.antennas_select_input = [<%= AntennaInstalled.all.to_json %>];
}
```